# Aws disaster recovery scenario for nat gateways ip addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, cloud, devops, nat

I have NAT gateways with very important IP addresses that are allowed to access some government sites. It can take a few weeks to approve a new address to gain access. Here is my question: Is there an option, in case of a disaster, to have the same NAT gateway addresses in another region, or at least in the same region?

The documentation states that NAT gateway addresses are generated randomly and cannot be  selected, but perhaps there is a solution.

Comment: NAT Gateways MUST have an Elastic IP associated, and the EIP is, by its nature, persistent and can subsequently be reassociated with another NAT Gateway in the same region.

Comment: What about another region?

Comment: You cannot move an EIP between regions, but you cannot lose an EIP because it's a completely virtual entity. I guess you can only lose it if Amazon decides to completely delete an entire region from the global infrastructure or if you disable that region from your account.

Comment: if in case of disaster when the whole region is not enable or AWS account was hacked and all resources were deleted ,  is there any option to reserve the ip addresses?

Comment: What kind of disaster is "the whole region is not enable"? As I said, an Elastic IP cannot be "broken" even by a region outage because is not a physical entity. There's no way to reserve an IP address forever, cross-region  and/or cross-account.

Comment: @FilippoTestini interesting, so in cases where the NAT IPs are whitelisted and loosing such IP can have catastrophic amplification, there is no way to preserve ownership of IP?
There is an option to move eip between ec2 instance, there is no such option for Nat gateways?

Comment: @matisa it is indeed possible inside the same region and the same account, just like the ec2 instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NAT Gateways **must** have an Elastic IP associated, and the EIP is, by its nature, persistent and can subsequently be reassociated with another NAT Gateway in the same region.

The Elastic IP is also one of the mandatory property that you must set during a NAT Gateway creation:

[image: NAT Gateway creation]

It's true that you cannot move an EIP between regions, but you cannot lose an EIP because it's a completely virtual entity.
I guess you can only lose it if Amazon decides to completely delete an entire region from the global infrastructure or if you disable that region from your account.